# Need help installing ejabberd on Centos/RHEL7 with SELinux and reverse proxy

Tags: centos, haproxy, selinux, ejabberd

I've been trying to get a web client to use EJabberd on the recommended port (5281) through a reverse proxy (HAProxy) on Centos7 with SELinux enabled.  I am not familiar with SELinux context rules.

The basic problem seems to be that HAProxy cannot open port 5281.  I've installed the `ejabberd-selinux` package thinking that would help on both the proxy system and the system running EJabber.  The ejabberd-selinux seems to configure the standard ports except 5281 which I subsequently attempted to configure myself.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two things listening on the same port.  Either it should be `ejabberd` or it should be `haproxy`.  Usually you'd put `haproxy` in front of `ejabberd` so if you want clients to connect on port 5281 then that's the port `haproxy` needs to listen on.  Then the `ejabberd` is on some arbitrary port and you put that port number in your `backend` section of the `haproxy.cfg`.

Comment: Thanks, but I should have said that ejabberd and haproxy are running on separate systems.

Answer (score 0):

1. You could check whether ejabberd listen on port 5281 only in localhost interface or all interface.
2. CentOS 7 comes with firewalld as default firewall management tools, you can use this service to allow/open specific port to your server

[firewalld](https://firewalld.org/)

[How to setup firewall on centos 7 with firewalld](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-setup-a-firewall-with-firewalld-on-centos-7/)